# Need help in MongoDB Aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have a collection called `orders`

```
{
 "order_id":"123",
 "user_id":"u1",
 "history": [ "sh1","sh2" ]
}
{
 "order_id":"111",
 "user_id":"u1",
 "history": [ "sh3" ]
}
```

StatusHistory

```
{
  id: "sh1",
  event: "order_placed",
  amount: 100,
  timestamp: ".."
},
{
  id: "sh2",
  event: "do_refund",
  amount: 50,
  timestamp: ".."
},
{
  id: "sh3",
  event: "placed",
  amount: 300,
  timestamp: ".."
},
```

I have set a for loop doing required task, but need to optimize it.
For single user, for all orders I need to populate history for that order and do sum of amount (for `placed` ) and subtract amount `do_refund`.

This is my effort to do the same. I need help.

```
db.getCollection('orders').aggregate(
[
    {
        $match: {
            user_id: 'u1',
        }
    },
    {

        $project: {
            order_id: 1,
            history:1,
            user_id:1
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$history'
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "status_history",
            localField: "history",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "status_history_object"
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            'status_history_object.event': 'placed'
        }
    }
    //        ,
    //        {
    //            $group:
    //                {
    //                    _id: null,
    //                    sum: { $sum: "$status_history_object.payload.prices.amount_paid" }
    //                }
    //        }
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

- `$group` - to calculate **total placed** and **total refund**.
- `$subtract` - to calculate **total**.

```js
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "user_id": "u1"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      order_id: 1,
      history: 1,
      user_id: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "status_history",
      localField: "history",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "status_history_object"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$status_history_object"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": null,
      "total_placed": {
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": {
            "if": {
              "$eq": [
                "$status_history_object.event",
                "placed"
              ]
            },
            "then": "$status_history_object.amount",
            "else": 0
          }
        }
      },
      "total_refund": {
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": {
            "if": {
              "$eq": [
                "$status_history_object.event",
                "do_refund"
              ]
            },
            "then": "$status_history_object.amount",
            "else": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      total: {
        $subtract: [
          "$total_placed",
          "$total_refund"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mAb13TTiH5Y)

Comment: Thank you so much @NeNaD . Saved hours of mine! Means a lot!